# Using XCTAssertEqual in a Xcode UI test with react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am testing an app using the Xcode UI tester.  Each page of the app has some title text. When the test visits a page, I would like to test the title text using `XCTAssertEqual`.

The react-native for the page looks like this

```
  <View style={[AppStyles.appContainer, AppStyles.container]}>
    <NavigationBar
      title={<NavbarTitle title= {this.state.title} />}
      statusBar={{style: 'light-content', hidden: false}}
      style={AppStyles.navbar}
      tintColor={AppConfig.primaryColor}
      leftButton={leftButton} />
    <route.component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...route.passProps} onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}  />
  </View>
```

and the code for the NavBarTitle Component is

```
var NavbarTitle = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Text style={[AppStyles.baseText, AppStyles.strong, AppStyles.navbarTitle]}>{this.props.title}</Text>
    );
  }
});
```

I would like to write the assertion as something like this

```
XCTAssertEqual(NavbarTitle.text, 'Sign In')
```

How do I find the NavbarTitle.text with XCTAssertEqual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to just look for the title text, rather than the title element.  The following code waits for the text to appear and then asserts it does exist.

```
  let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
  let signIn = app.staticTexts[" Sign In"]
  expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: signIn, handler: nil)
  waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15, handler: nil)
  XCTAssert(signIn.exists)
```

This can have a false positive on other pages which happen to have 'Sign In' displayed on the page, so would be preferable to identify the exact element.